# Redirection website witout www to www doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I trie to redirect my website domain.com to www.domain.com on my new server but It doesn't work. I tried with virtual host and .htaccess without succes.. Do you have any idea what is the problem ?

My host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

    <Directory "/var/www/domain">
        Options -Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
        RewriteRule .* index.php 
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-error.log


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.(htm|html|php|asp)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" - care to elaborate?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1` Is your domain **domain.com**?

Comment: @Whathaveyoutried I think in this rare instance, "doesn't work," in context of the sentence it's in, explains the problem.

Comment: @Popnoodles Does it mean that the redirect fails, or that the 'www' version of his domain doesn't load. I can't tell ..

Comment: Let's go for www.domain.com renders a page and domain.com doesn't return anything.

Comment: domain.com retun a page It works (default to Apache i guess and I have Apache 2.2), www.domain.com works fine

Comment: @slig36 Please click edit under the question, and clarify exactly what currently happens.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Apache 2.2, you need to have a [`NameVirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive for this site's IP address in order for both VirtualHost blocks to be in use.

Otherwise, Apache will pick the first one which matches the IP address and port, ignoring ServerName and ServerAlias lines (the same happens if no ServerName or ServerAlias matches the request).

[This directive is no longer necessary in Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost), however, so if you're running that, please ignore this answer.

Alternatively, since you're domain rewrite already tests HTTP_HOST, you can move it into the same VirtualHost block as the rest of your rules and content anyway. Make sure to put it before the other rules which manipulate the URL.